# How to export Palette-Based png in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Because the nmlc ask me to add palette, so I am trying to create a palette-based png with GIMP. But I didn't see the option for palette, only the RGB, RGBA, GRAY, GRAYA. According to [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5), png have 3 types, but i only see two in GIMP(whether with or without Alpha channel). Is there a way to add palette in png file?

I was trying to find a way to add palette to the picture, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is color-indexed in Gimp (`Image > Mode > Color indexed`) then it will be exported as a color-indexed PNG.

But keep in mind that in Gimp, "Color-indexed" is really "Color-indexed GIF-style", so opacity is binary and not progressive. This of course is not a problem if your image has no transparent parts.